# Beans Binding for JTrees

Tags: java, swing, jtree, beans-binding

Is beans binding for `JTree`s currently supported? I've found [this forum post from 2008](http://www.java.net/node/682044), but I didn't know if there was any development.

If it does exist does anyone know where i might find some documentation on it?

Comment: not directly about JTree, maybe this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html

Comment: I've used this on other parts of my GUI, mainly using it for validation but I cant find anything on binding JTrees.

Comment: I never used this Framework, but JTree would be similair to the JTable, just structure is little bit complicated with Nodes for JTree

Comment: I've found support for JTable with binding, but it would be useless in the context I am using it. Doesn't matter I'll find another way, I don't think it exists.

Comment: Further update on this, I've stopped using beans binding all together now. its not supported in JDK7, I've turned to JGoodies I will bind the Tree Model to the Presentation model and try it that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no beans binding, but the closest thing I know of would be NetBeans Nodes API with Explorer API. Using `BeanNode` and `BeanTreeView` ordinary Java Beans would be quite easy to bind to a `JTree`. This http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html tutorial goes much deeper, but the basic idea should be there. Depending on your use case this might not be that useful, but I find Node much easier to work with than pure `TreeModel`.